# Getting a list of currently connected BLE devices

Tags: raspbian

I am trying to figure out a way to list the currently connected (and not just paired) bluetooth devices. I was wondering if there was an easy way to do this using pybluez. I need to trigger events based on the fact if a certain device is connected or not.

I am using a Raspberry Pi 3. Also, I understand that BLE devices periodically change their address, so, is there any way to check for a certain device repeatedly?

P.S. I am a beginner for both python and RPi.

Comment: Use `bluetoothctl` →  `info AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF` for getting [device states](http://www.linux-magazine.com/Issues/2017/197/Command-Line-bluetoothctl#article_f4).

Comment: The question answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21000817/6602159).

Comment: @M. Rostami That question only deals with devices that are nearby (not connected). Thanks for the effort, though.

Comment: @Ephemeral I did come across bluetoothctl and systemctl but don't really understand how to use either of them in Python. I know it can be done using a terminal, I know that much.

Comment: @PlytonRexus, You can use this [python lib](https://pypi.org/project/PyBluez/) and follow [this instructions](https://pybluez.github.io/).  The project Development Status is Beta. You can find examples [here](https://github.com/pybluez/pybluez/tree/master/examples/ble)

Answer (score 3):

On the command line, you can request a list of connected BT devices with

```
$ hcitool con
Connections:
> ACL 9C:65:B0:A0:1E:BD handle 11 state 1 lm MASTER AUTH ENCRYPT
```

Once you parse the MAC addresses from the output, you can check the device identity with

```
$ hcitool name "9C:65:B0:A0:1E:BD"
MY Mobile (GT-I9300I)
```

Even more info can be obtained with

```
$ hcitool info 9C:65:B0:A0:1E:BD
Requesting information ...
BD Address:  9C:65:B0:A0:1E:BD
OUI Company: Samsung Electronics Co.,Ltd (9C-65-B0)
Device Name: MY Mobile (GT-I9300I)
LMP Version: 4.0 (0x6) LMP Subversion: 0x7d3
Manufacturer: Qualcomm (29)
Features page 0: 0xff 0xfe 0x8f 0xfe 0xd8 0x3f 0x5b 0x87
...
```

Comment: It should be the accepted answer...